# How to reboot Sony Xperia V?

Tags: reboot, sony-xperia-v

How can I reboot Sony Xperia V?

If I long press the physical power button, it only gives me an option to shut it down. If I long press that button, it actually asks me to reboot the phone, albeit in safe mode. I don't want that, I just want to reboot in unsafe mode.

Comment: Soo un-enthusiast let's try to boost that mood. Alright, which device do you have? Because the override shutdown can be different per manufacturer. Also what do you consider a long press?  Off the top of my head the standard override shutdown is to > hold down power button for at least thirty  seconds or till it shutsdown.  For some Samsung devices override shutdown and reboot is to > hold down power button + volume down  until it shuts down and then it will automatically reboot.

Comment: It says Xperia SOL21 on the back. The power button and volume down buttons are terrible close to each other. I can't touch both with two fingers.

Comment: OK the Sony Xperia VL the first try holding power down + volume up at the same time. This might take you to recovery mode but you can restart from there too.

Comment: Pressing the power button for a long time without interaction on the screen long enough shuts most android devices off immediatly and restarts them. So keep pressing till it goes black should do the trick in 90% of the time.

Comment: There are many apps in Play Store that provides widget to reboot the phone. Tapping such widget would reboot the phone normally. It is strange that normal reboot option isn't present in your device. You can change that power button menu and add normal reboot option if you've root access.